# For what and from where is Compiler-RT invoked?

Tags: compiler-construction, runtime, clang, llvm, llvm-clang

I would like to know the following about LLVM's Compiler-RT project: from what program is it invoked.  To my understanding, Compiler-RT is a collection of functions that handle instructions in LLVM that don't really have hardware counterparts (is there more to it than this?).  So if I use division in LLVM, it should be replaced by an appropriate Compiler-RT function.  First, if this is not correct, please correct me!

Second, I am curious as to who generates the Compiler-RT usage.  Is it Clang or is it LLVM directly.  Could I write a different front-end to LLVM and would LLVM automatically handle the use of Compiler-RT when appropriate?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Both your assertions are correct. A LLVM backend has to map LLVM IR to native target-specific instructions. If an instruction is not supported natively, it has to be replaced (legalized).
You can see this taking place in [TargetLowering](http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/TargetLoweringBase_8cpp_source.html), which directly maps to runtime functions in the [Compiler RT](http://llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/compiler-rt/trunk/README.txt).

The front end is not involved.